# Create rows based on substring of column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to build a data frame from the following:

```
seq_name <- c('sequence1', 'sequence2')
seqs <- c('ATCGGA', 'TTGCGA')
seq_length <- 6
```

Here we have two sequences, called `sequence1` and `sequence2` which are both 6 letters long (e.g. `ATCGGA`)

I want to make a data frame that has three columns:

- sample - containing the sequence name - e.g.: `sequence1`
- seq - containing the sequence -  e.g.: `ATCGGA`
- pos - containing an index position for each position in `1:length(seq)` - e.g.: `1`

I am doing this as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(rep(seq_name, seq_length) , rep(seqs, seq_length), pos=seq(1:seq_length))
colnames(df) <- c("sample", "seq", "pos")
str(df)
```

However, this is not quite producing the right result as I have no `pos=2` for `sequence1` :

```
df %>% 
  arrange(sample) %>% 
  head()
```

---

```
           sample    seq pos
1 sequence1 ATCGGA   1
2 sequence1 ATCGGA   3
3 sequence1 ATCGGA   5
4 sequence1 ATCGGA   1
5 sequence1 ATCGGA   3
6 sequence1 ATCGGA   5
```

Whereas I want:

```
     sample    seq pos
1 sequence1 ATCGGA   1
2 sequence1 ATCGGA   2
3 sequence1 ATCGGA   3
4 sequence1 ATCGGA   4
5 sequence1 ATCGGA   5
6 sequence1 ATCGGA   6
```

I then want to iterate over each row, and for each position in `pos` take the letter from `seq` that corresponds to that position.

For example:

The expected outputshould be:

```
     sample    seq   pos   nuc
      <fctr> <fctr> <int> <chr>
 1 sequence1 ATCGGA     1     A
 2 sequence1 ATCGGA     2     T
 3 sequence1 ATCGGA     3     C
 4 sequence1 ATCGGA     4     G
 5 sequence1 ATCGGA     5     G
...
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  arrange(sample, pos) %>% 
  mutate(nuc = substr(seq, 1:n(), pos) )
```

However, this is not giving me my expected result. Instead the first two rows are:

```
      sample    seq   pos   nuc
      <fctr> <fctr> <int> <chr>
 1 sequence1 ATCGGA     1     A
 2 sequence1 ATCGGA     1      
 3 sequence1 ATCGGA     3     C
 4 sequence1 ATCGGA     3      
 5 sequence1 ATCGGA     5     G
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(sample) %>% mutate(nuc = substr(seq, pos, pos))`

Comment: @akrun - that looks good! However, I can see now that I am building the df incorrectly. I have 2 `pos = 1` rows for `sequence1 `. Can you see what I've done wrong?

Comment: @akrun - I'll update the question. `table(df$pos[df$sample=='sequence1'])` shows the problem - I get 2 entries for position `1`, `3` and `5` for `sequence1`

Comment: Do you need `df %>% arrange(sample) %>% group_by(sample) %>% mutate(pos = row_number(), nuc = substr(seq, pos, pos))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated expected output, after `arrange`ing the 'sample', grouped by 'sample', update the 'pos' as the `row_number` and then do the `substr` based on 'pos'

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
         arrange(sample) %>% 
         group_by(sample) %>% 
         mutate(pos = row_number(), 
                nuc = substr(seq, pos, pos)) 

head(out, 6)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   sample [1]
#  sample    seq      pos nuc  
#  <fct>     <fct>  <int> <chr>
#1 sequence1 ATCGGA     1 A    
#2 sequence1 ATCGGA     2 T    
#3 sequence1 ATCGGA     3 C    
#4 sequence1 ATCGGA     4 G    
#5 sequence1 ATCGGA     5 G    
#6 sequence1 ATCGGA     6 A
```